# Builds from Github Failing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are currently in the process of setting up CI for our rails application. The code is hosted on github. Up until now everything has gone very smoothly, how ever we have run into an issue where code pushes to github are causing failures on the build before the code is even checked out.

This is the output from Jenkins:

```
Started by user Jeremy Rottman
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SweetyHigh-Staging/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SweetyHigh-Staging/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@46ffed1d
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision a40cbe653169bc73c445f39e09dcd8cfe66e5fe7 (origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:Sweety-High/sweetyhigh.git
Commencing build of Revision a40cbe653169bc73c445f39e09dcd8cfe66e5fe7 (origin/master)
Checking out Revision a40cbe653169bc73c445f39e09dcd8cfe66e5fe7 (origin/master)
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to parse changelog
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:600)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at jenkins.plugin.assembla.AssemblaSCMListener.onChangeLogParsed(AssemblaSCMListener.java:32)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:598)
... 6 more
```

Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log shows that you have the [Assembla plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Assembla+plugin) installed and that your builds are failing because of a bug in that plugin (a `NullPointerException`).

From a brief look at the source code, it looks like it's failing because you have the plugin installed, but haven't configured any Assembla sites in the global Jenkins configuration.

I filed this bug as [JENKINS-14431](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14431).